# how to call supportFragmentManager for dialogFragment in onBindViewHolder?

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-dialogfragment

i have a problem here, idk how to show dialogFragment in my Adapter. i want to everytime my itemView click it will show my dialogFragment

this is my onBindViewHolder

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val type = list[position]
    holder.binding.tvTitle.text = type.title
    holder.binding.tvIsiNotes.text = type.content

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        val dialogFragment = AddFragment()
        dialogFragment.show(supportFragmentManager, null)
    }


    if(position == list.size - 1){
        onLoad?.let {
            it()
        }
    }
}
```

this is my code using navigationcomponent, but i want to show the Dialog.

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
        val action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToEditFragment(type)
        holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a custom click listener class to pass as a parameter of your adapter:

```
class YourAdapter(
    private val clickListener: (type: Int) -> Unit
) { 
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val type = list[position]
        ...
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(clickListener(type))
        ...
    }
}
```

Then, instantiate your adapter as:

```
val adapter = YourAdapter { it ->
    findNavController().navigate(HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToEditFragment(it))
}
```

Comment: where can i add AddFragment().show(childFramentManager, "AddFragment")?

Comment: In the fragment where you are instantiating your recycler view adapter

Comment: im getting some error because on of the parameter clicklistener. i want just show my dialogFragment, this is my code using navigationcomponent holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val action = HomeFragmentDirections.actionHomeFragmentToEditFragment(type)
            holder.itemView.findNavController().navigate(action)
        } . in this case it directed to the fragment, i just want to show the dialogFragment. can you help me?

Comment: i updated my code in the question

Comment: Ok, if you need to navigate to the dialog fragment the edited answer should work (I assumed that type is an Int, change the type of the parameter if you need to.